# I having trouble try to connect my p-trap to the wall drain pipe

Tags: walls, drain, pipe

My wall drain pipe is facing down, so I am having a hard time trying to connect the p-trap to the wall drain pipe because of the angle.

[image: wall drain pipe facing down]

Comment: that's part of an old p-trap, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

That downward facing pipe is part of an old p-trap you'll need to remove it and replace it with a new pipe.

Perhaps it unscrews you'll have to investigate further.